# Jquery - radio button returning undefined / ""

Tags: jquery

A Jquery radio button function is not returning any values on my webpage, I have other jquery function working on the same page but can't figure how to identify what is missing ??

```
 $(".liCalss").change(function () {

        var catSelected = $("#cat").size() == 1 && $("[name='categories']:checked").val() != "fixedclass" ? $("[name='categories']:checked").val() : "";
        var city = $('div.mainMenusHolder ul.mainMenus li a.active').attr('id');
        //var catSelected = $("[name='categories']:checked").val();
        var cityName = "";
        var wrapUrl;


        $("#homePageGallery").hide();
        $("#homePageGallery1").show();

        $("#homePageGallery img").attr("src", "/images/TourListBanner/VatBannernew.png");
```

Comment: Can you provide your HTML or a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=RzPsPclnb3 its kinda hard to show you with all the code thats there... the code works but when i go through in the debugger i see everything like - undefined and ""

Comment: is there a way to find out why items are undefined

Answer (score 1):

May be the event does not hooked in to the DOM.

Try like this:

```
$('body').on('change','.liCalss',function(){
    // Your code here
})
```

Comment: when i click the button javascript does start - but it goes through all Jquery with null/""/undefined - like nothing is returned from the radio buttons